# XSLT: XML-XML (No XML Tags in the transformed file)

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm very new to XSLT and tried to translate a given XML file into another.

The original file has the following structure:

```
<metadataContainerType xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"xmlns:ns3="http://textgrid.info/namespaces/metadata/core/2010">
<ns3:object>
    <ns3:generic>
        <ns3:provided>
            <ns3:title>Tfghfv</ns3:title>
            <ns3:identifier type="METSXMLID">T0072-00213-THUMB</ns3:identifier>
            <ns3:format>image/jpeg</ns3:format>
        </ns3:provided>
        <ns3:generated>
                <ns3:created>2012-11-07T11:30:20.085+01:00</ns3:created>
                <ns3:lastModified>2012-11-07T11:30:20.085+01:00</ns3:lastModified>
                <ns3:issued>2012-11-07T11:30:20.085+01:00</ns3:issued>
                <ns3:revision>0</ns3:revision>
                <ns3:extent>7055</ns3:extent>
                <ns3:project id="TGPR-1e31ce14-d7d9-3023-e8c9-501a7552a1f2">St. Matthias Test 07</ns3:project>

        </ns3:generated>
    </ns3:generic>
 </ns3:object>
</metadataContainerType>
```

and I want to transform it into the form:

```
<add><doc>
    <field name="id">455HHS-2232</field>
    <field name="title">T0072-00031-DOWNLOAD - Blatt 12v</field>
    <field name="format">application/pdf</field>
    <field name="created">2012-11-07T11:15:19.887Z</field>
    <field name="last_modified">2012-11-07T11:15:19.887Z</field>
    <field name="issued">2012-11-07T11:15:19.887Z</field>
</doc></add>
```

But when I transform the file I miss the XML tags it just show the content of the nodes.
Maybe someone of you can help me.

A snapshot of my XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:ns3="http://textgrid.info/namespaces/metadata/core/2010">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/ns3:object">
     <add><doc>

         <!-- the provided metadata fields -->
        <field name="title">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ns3:generic/ns3:provided/ns3:title"/>
        </field>

        <field name="identifier_type">
            <xsl:value-of select="ns3:generic/ns3:provided/ns3:identifier_type"/>
        </field>


        <xsl:element name="field">
            <xsl:value-of select="ns3:generic/ns3:provided/ns3:format"/>
        </xsl:element>
    ...
    </doc></add>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template matches `/ns3:object`. This means to match an `ns3:object` element which is a child of the root node. Since the `ns3:object` element in your source XML is a child of `metadataContainerType` and not the root node, your template should simply match `ns3:object` (without the leading slash).

Comment: What a stupid fault, thank you very much.

But I came to another problem. 

I had to add in the xsl:stylesheet tag "xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:ns3="http://textgrid.info/namespaces/metadata/core/2010" .

When I transalte the XML file this part is added to the "add"-tag and it looks like this:"<add xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:ns3="http://textgrid.info/namespaces/metadata/core/2010">"

But I can't use the tag with this information for the next step.

Comment: This seems like an unrelated issue. Please ask a new question.